# Ascribe string to variables Angular Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, split

Here's my json :

```
[
    {
        "name": "1QQQJohnQQQ11_22_1998",
        "age" : "ads"
    },
    {
        "name": "2QQQEvaQQQ05_01_1989",
        "age" : "ads"
    },
    {
        "name": "3QQQCasperQQQ02_16_1994",
        "age" : "ads"
    },
    {
        "name": "4QQQBeanQQQ30_12_1996",
        "age" : "ads"
    }]
```

I do from that a table, and what i have to do is split "QQQ" from name and change it on 3 strings (ex. "4", "Bean", "30_12_1996"),
How do it in js file, by ascribe each string to variable (ex. type = "4", name = "Bean", date = "30_12_1996). 
My js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("filejson.json").then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function(){
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, service){
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.names = data.data;
            console.log($scope.names);
        });
  //*what i try to do (it didn't works):
 var type = names.name.split('QQQ')[0];
 var name= names.name.split('QQQ')[1];
 var date= names.name.split('QQQ')[2];
 //*
});
```

Comment: Splitting the string like that should work. I think your problem is elsewhere. When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? What is the error? What is the output?

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the javascript `map` function to map the array from one format to another and use the string `split` method.

```
var a = [
    {
        name: "1QQQJohnQQQ11_22_1998",
        age : "ads"
    },
    {
        name: "2QQQEvaQQQ05_01_1989",
        age : "ads"
    },
    {
        name: "3QQQCasperQQQ02_16_1994",
        age : "ads"
    },
    {
        name: "4QQQBeanQQQ30_12_1996",
        age : "ads"
    }];


var result = a.map(function (value, index, array) { 
                    varsplitValue = value.name.split("QQQ");
                    value["SNo"] = varsplitValue[0];
                    value["personName"] = varsplitValue[1]; 
                    value["dob"] = varsplitValue[2];
                    return value;
} );
```

`result` contains the array after calling the map function.

`result[0].SNO` would display the SNO of first person (1).

`result[0].personName` would display the first person name (John).

`result[0].dob` would display the first person date of birth (11_22_1998).

Answer (score 0):

**Use JavaScript [**map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method :**

**working demo :**

```js
var a = [
    {
        name: "1QQQJohnQQQ11_22_1998",
        age : "ads"
    },
    {
        name: "2QQQEvaQQQ05_01_1989",
        age : "ads"
    },
    {
        name: "3QQQCasperQQQ02_16_1994",
        age : "ads"
    },
    {
        name: "4QQQBeanQQQ30_12_1996",
        age : "ads"
    }];
    
a.map(function(item) {
  item.type = item.name.split('QQQ')[0];
  item.date = item.name.split('QQQ')[2];
  item.name = item.name.split('QQQ')[1];
});    
console.log(a);
```